# Display a single element of an array

Tags: php, variables

I think it is a very simple question but for a long time I am trying to figure this out:

I need to store the number 18 ([term_id]) from the following array in a variable, how can I do this?

```
Array (
    [0] => WP_Term Object (
       [term_id] => 18 
       [name] => Im Rebgarten 
       [slug] => im-rebgarten 
       [term_group] => 0 
       [term_taxonomy_id] => 18 
       [taxonomy] => give_forms_category 
       [description] => 
       [parent] => 0 
       [count] => 1 
       [filter] => raw 
       [object_id] => 900
   ) 
)
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply access the variable from object by `->` notation like

```
$array = array();//Your current array
$term_variable = $array[0]->term_id; //store the term_id into the variable
print_r($term_variable); //prints the variable
```